# How to access proxima nova tabular figures on a webpage?

Tags: html, css, fonts

The problem is that by default Proxima Nova numbers are not monospaced. Therefore a simple price list table does not line up. (see Figure 1)

[image: Misaligned numbers]
*Figure 1. Misaligned numbers*

The question is:

- is there some CSS rule to access monospaced numbers?
- is there some HTML code trick so I can access monospaced numbers as characters? (sth like `&#8721;`)
- or should I use `<span class="figure">1</span><span class="figure">2</span>`...?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

[CSS3 Fonts’ `font-variant-numeric`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#propdef-font-variant-numeric). This allows you to toggle Opentype features. In your case this would be:

```
.my-element { font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums; }
```

Proxima Nova [lists support for tabular figures](http://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/proxima-nova) so that’s good, but I’m not sure about browser support for font-variant-numeric. If that doesn’t work then you could try [`font-feature-settings`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#propdef-font-feature-settings) instead which should give you the same effect with [(possibly) more support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-feature):

```
.my-element { font-feature-settings: "tnum" on; }
```

The specification does say though that:

> Authors should generally use ‘font-variant’ and its related subproperties whenever possible.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for trying to help, +1. can you please add a link to the specification? (-webkit-font-feature-settings does not seem to work correctly, font-variant-numeric does not seem to exist on Chrome.)

Comment: `font-feature-settings` should work in IE (no prefix) / Firefox (`-moz-` until next version) / Chrome (`-webkit-`) but has no support in Safari. I can’t find any resources for `font-variant-numeric` support, would guess that it hasn’t been implemented in browsers yet. As for Opentype features, I don’t know how you’re serving Proxima Nova but it’s possible support for tabular numerals is being stripped. Any more information on that?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. The CSS is

```
.tabular-numbers {
  -moz-font-feature-settings:"tnum" 1; /* Firefox 31+ */
  -moz-font-feature-settings:"tnum=1"; 
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'tnum' 1; /* Chrome 31+, Android 4.4+, Opera 24+ */
  font-feature-settings: 'tnum' 1; /* IE10+ */
}
```

References: http://clagnut.com/sandbox/css3/ and http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-feature

Contrary to answers to: [No support for font-feature-settings in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275418/no-support-for-font-feature-settings-in-safari) , I have seen **no support** on Mac Safari 7.1.

So the only universally working solution is currently:

```
.tabular-figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

and `<span class="tabular-figure">5</span><span class="tabular-figure">6</span><span class="tabular-figure">7</span><span class="tabular-figure">1</span>`

which is a crap, so more like

```
.number{
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}
<span class="number">5671</span>
```

Looks like Apple Safari is becoming the new Internet Explorer...  :@@@