# font-feature-settings property with tnum - not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

With reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212555/how-to-access-proxima-nova-tabular-figures-on-a-webpage), I tried using `font-feature-settings` CSS property for changing the **Proxima Nova** font styles to support tabular format for numbers. My element will be like

```
<a class="test">1111</a>
<a class="test">876</a>
```

and my CSS declaration will be like

```
.test {

-moz-font-feature-settings:"tnum" 1; 
-ms-font-feature-settings:"tnum" 1; 
-o-font-feature-settings:"tnum" 1; 
-webkit-font-feature-settings:"tnum" 1; 
font-feature-settings:"tnum" 1;

}
```

But still my output doesn't look as expected. It's something looks like the old:

[image: Screenshot After CSS Fix]

What can be the perfect fix for this?

Comment: "What can be the perfect fix for this?" There isn't one. font-feature-settings is poorly supported and you can't change that.

Comment: Well... I can think of a way, but my answer will probably be voted down or thrown out as irrelevant, so: You can achieve the "perfect fix" by creating your text in a SVG graphics editor (on the machine your font is installed), then convert the text to paths and publish it to the web... either that or a nasty JS hack.